# Styling a dynamic menu using css

Tags: php, html, css

I have this simple code that creates a menu using HTML:

```
<?php
    // Get current page file name
    $page = basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
?>

<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php" <?php if ($page == "index.php") echo 'class="current"' ?>>Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="resume.php" <?php if ($page == "resume.php") echo 'class="current"' ?>>Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="photography.php" <?php if ($page == "photography.php") echo 'class="current"' ?>>Photography</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php" <?php if ($page == "about.php") echo 'class="current"' ?>>About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php" <?php if ($page == "contact.php") echo 'class="current"' ?>>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Also i have this piece of code in css for styling it:

```
#navigation ul li a.current {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

These are in htdocs and when i go to localhost/foldername/first.php (first being the first piece of code) i get a simple menu and css is not affecting it.How can i connect this menu with the css code so i can modify it?Is the css code wrong?
P.S: The css code is in a .css file in the same directory

Comment: Is your CSS file linked to the HTML document in the `<head>`?

Comment: On the page header is css linked?

Comment: This is going to be a path issue. Open up your browser's dev tools, click the _Network_ tab, and refresh the page. What errors do you see? Is your CSS file one of the errors? If so, look at the path that it is requesting. Unless you setup a virtual host, `localhost` will be included in the path. If the path to your CSS file starts with a slash, i.e. `/css/style.css`, the browser will try to load it from localhost, i.e. `/localhost/css/style.css`. This breaks because there is no folder `localhost`. Use relative paths or setup a var that points to localhost when developing and slash on live.